udev rule odd behavior with bluray disc drive
I have a udev rule that runs a script when a bluray disc is loaded.  I am aware of the time limit on udev scripts and so have the script run a child script with the "at now" command.
The child script then does a bunch of ripping and post processing.  The strange behavior is that any attempt to read the disc label returns an empty string when run from udev.  But, if I run the same script from the command line, it has no problem spinning up the disc and reading the label.  in fact, I even have a test script that I tried that only loops and tries to read the label and echo to a text file.  It sits and loops outputting an empty string.  Whats also weird is that any media check in the udev script says the disc is loaded and ready to go.
udev rule:
UBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="1", ENV{ID_TYPE}=="cd", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/autodisk '%E(DEVNAME)'"

udev script autodisk:
#!/bin/bash

{
  if [ "$ID_CDROM_MEDIA_BD" -eq "1" ]; then
    echo /home/nathan/rom_ready $DEVNAME | at now
    exit 1
  fi
}

rom_ready script
#!/bin/bash
counter=0

device=$1

echo $device >  /home/nathan/.var/log/diskrip/.diskripper.log
while true; do

  file -s $device >> /home/nathan/.var/log/diskrip/.diskripper.log
  sleep 1
  echo "loop" >>  /home/nathan/.var/log/diskrip/.diskripper.log
  discname=$(blkid -o value -s LABEL $device)
  echo $discname >>  /home/nathan/.var/log/diskrip/.diskripper.log

  counter=$((counter + 1))
  if [ $counter -ge 20 ]; then break; fi
  
done 

the line file -s $device >> ~/log.text writes "/dev/sr0: data" to the log file, but that shouldn't happen if the disc isn't ready to read.
While rom_ready is looping and failing to output the disc label, if I open a terminal and read the label, i can get the label from the command line, but the rom_ready keeps getting blank data.  Also if I run the rom_ready from the terminal instead of from udev, it executes as expected. It's like when I put the disc in and udev is the only thing that initiates an action, the system thinks the disc has been read from, but nothing has actually been read, so all the fields are empty.  Whats also weird is that if I include a call to makemkvcon in the udev script, it has no problem loading and ripping the disc as well as naming the file.  It just sucks, because I can't automate naming of the directories ahead of time.
This doesn't seem to be a problem with regular dvd discs.  It reads the label, creates a directory with the name of the movie title, and then rips the disk into that directory.

Remove a whold class of potential problems by vetting your script at https://shellcheck.net. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or whatever) as the first line. Fix any flagged issues and update your question above. Also try running your script with set -x as the 2nd line in the file. you will see each line of code that is executed (preceded by + char), where all cmd-substituions and variable values are visible. What you see after each + is the exact code that the script tried to execute.

Unless you have been looking at the wrong file (you do realize ~ in udev rule would mean /root right?), it sounds like blkid is somehow not working when run with udev rule. Have you checked whether lsblk makes a difference? Also, have you been deleting the file after you looked at it? Just in case the file isn't really being updated at all because you made some mistake after maybe changing the script or udev rule? (Also, why don't you just pass the ID_FS_LABEL env to the script?)

Also %E should be followed by curly braces, not parentheses. And if you want to leverage ID_FS_LABEL, make sure the rule file is prefixed with a number larger than 60.

@TomYan  I simplified the directory for clarity, but I know for a fact that the script is running as it outputs to the log file, and of course the more complicated version calls all of the ripping/processing software as expected.  It really does seem that blkid doesn't like udev.  have you been deleting the file after you looked at it? Yes, I make sure to delete the log file each run.  I'll give the ID_FS_LABEL a shot.  if I can get that to work it seems like the most consistent way to make it work.
